# Elf Symtab Parsing Null Pointer

Tags: c, assembly, elf

Hate to ask people to help me debug my code but really stuck on this. I have a simple code snippet for going through the symbols in symtab and then printing them to the console. Apparently, I have an null pointer in the calls to `printf` and `strcmp` (resulting in segfault), but I can't seem to figure out why.
Here is the code snippet:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <elf.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>


    #ifdef DEBUG
    #define PRINTDEBUG(x) printf x //variable number of arguments
    #else
    #define PRINTDEBUG(x) do{} while(0)
    #endif

    uint32_t main(int argc, char** argv){
        char* filename = argv[1];
        char* sym_name = argv[2];
        int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
        struct stat st;
        stat(fd, &st);


    char mem[st.st_size];
        read(fd, mem, st.st_size);

        Elf32_Ehdr* ehdr;
        Elf32_Shdr* shdr; //generic entry for enumerating sections
        Elf32_Shdr strtab; //holds string in symtab
        Elf32_Shdr symtab;
        char* sh_strtab; //hold sections names
        Elf32_Sym* sym;


        ehdr = (Elf32_Ehdr *)mem;
        shdr = (Elf32_Shdr* )(mem + ehdr->e_shoff);
        PRINTDEBUG(("number of section headers: %d\n", ehdr->e_shnum)); //need double brackets for variable #of arguments


        sh_strtab = (char *)(mem + (shdr[ehdr->e_shstrndx].sh_offset)); 

        //find address of symtab and strtab 
        for(int i = 0; i < ehdr->e_shnum; i++){
            if(shdr[i].sh_size){

            printf("%s\n", &sh_strtab[shdr[i].sh_name]);

            if(strcmp(&sh_strtab[shdr[i].sh_name], ".strtab") == 0)
                strtab = shdr[i];
            if(strcmp(&sh_strtab[shdr[i].sh_name], ".symtab") == 0)
                symtab = shdr[i];           

            }
        }
    PRINTDEBUG(("symtab offset %x\n", symtab.sh_offset));
    PRINTDEBUG(("strtab offset %x\n", strtab.sh_offset));

    char* symtab_str = (char *)(mem + strtab.sh_offset);
    sym = (Elf32_Sym* )(mem + symtab.sh_offset);

    printf("Symbol names: \n");
    for(int i = 0;  i < (symtab.sh_size / symtab.sh_entsize); i++, sym++){
        printf("%x\n",&symtab_str[sym->st_name]);
        if(strcmp(&symtab_str[sym->st_name], sym_name) ==0) 
            printf("not crahsed\n");

        //TODO: resolve reloc'd syms
    }
}
```

The null pointer occurs at `&symtab_str[sym->st_name]`. Weird thing is, I've looked at the assembly with the debugger and it shows `&symtab_str[sym->st_name]` pointing to the correct value, i.e. the first string in `.strtab`.

EDIT: Posted the code snippet that should trigger the segfault. Compile with "-m32" flag for gcc. Provide the pathname for a 32bit Elf file as the first run parameter. i.e.

```
./symtab_parse test_file
```

I already got this working as I originally intended. However, I am not sure about the cause of the segfault, and as pointed out by EmployedRussian, my original answer was not the root cause of the problem. Would like to really get to the bottom of this mystery, and hopefully learn something from it.

Comment: Why the cast in `sym = (Elf32_Sym* )(mem + symtab.sh_offset);`?

Comment: I'd compile with symbols using `-g` an inspect the C code before going down to assembler level.

Comment: A lot of code is missing, please share a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: On top of the missing code, you have misleading comments - if `symtab is (Elf32_Shdr) pointer to .symtab`, how can you access it with `.` rather than `->`?

Comment: I have reposted the full code snippet. Parameter char* file is just the pointer to the Elf file read into memory.

Comment: Did you try using a debugger to to check variable values as you single-step through it?

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see, the address stored in eax points to the first string in .strtab, so why am I getting a null pointer when passing this to strcmp?

The code snippet you showed appears to be correct, and if `eax` is `0xffd6a030` at the call to `strcmp`, then *by definition* it is not `NULL`.

Your (unsupported by evidence) assertion that it is `NULL` is what appears to be wrong (in other words, you are probably mis-interpreting something, and you *didn't show* that something).

Comment: I ran the strace and got the following output:

Comment: write(1, "Symbol names: \n", 15Symbol names: 
)        = 15
write(1, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to print the formatted output but as you can see, the si_addr field of the signal struct is 0, which I take to indicate a null pointer dereference

Comment: @JohnPeng You are getting `SIGSEGV` for `NULL` pointer dereference from *somewhere*, but not from the code you showed. `strace` is *really* the wrong tool for debugging this. Use a debugger?

Answer (score -2):

According to this section from the ELF specs:

> String table sections hold null-terminated character sequences,
>   commonly called strings.  The object uses these strings to represent
>   symbol and section names.  One references a string as an index into
>   the string table section.  The first byte, which is index zero, is
>   defined to hold a null character.

This means that symtab_str[0] points to a null character, which when dereferenced in strcmp, resulted in a Segfault. Modifying the code to check for the null string before performing the strcmp fixed the problem.

Comment: This is a completely bogus answer: passing *address* of a `NUL` character (as the example code does) is perfectly valid.

Comment: Then what would cause strcmp to segfault then?